# How to get the absolute path of my NPM global package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm building an NPM package that is supposed to run globally. 
Inside the NPM package, there's a `data` folder which contains a file I need to read at runtime.

How can I get the absolute path of my NPM package, so I can read the `data` folder?
I'm searching for that on Google with no luck.

Comment: `__filename` or `__dirname` global variables

Comment: thanks @ExplosionPills. If you answer I'll accept

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `path` [module](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) and with it either start your paths with a `./` or just omit any `/` at the begining of a string.

for example:

```
var path = require('path');
console.log(path.resolve('./');
```

is the same as

```
var path = require('path');
console.log(path.resolve('');
```

the `resolve` method is nice in that it'll resolve your relative path with an absolute path to it. Good to be safe!

To build on @explosion pills' comment, it's nice to combine `__dirname` and `path.resolve`

```
console.log(path.resolve(__dirname));
```

Comment: thanks for replying. When you are running an NPM global package, __dirname refers the directory the global package is being executed at, or does it refer to the global package installation folder (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/my-package) ?